# Angular UI Bootstrap - modal doesn't pop on the first click

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am trying to make a modal for login/register forms and wanted to make something that is reusable, I came across [this blog post](http://panthersoftware.com/blog/2013/05/09/a-reusable-bootstrap-modal-form-directive/) that goes through making a directive. I used that as well as angular-ui-bootstrap docs to make my modal. It does work, but the first time I click the button to pop the modal, it doesn't work. I can see the scope getting created using Batarang, but nothing pops. Subsequent clicks do work, and if I have 2 buttons, no matter which one I press first, it doesn't work, and after that either one works.

I made up a [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/OOjKJhIJlc6Y7goPhdBw) to show this. I am using templates etc so I added those. You can see that pressing "Register" or "Login" will not pop up the modal, but if you click again, the modals pop. You can also see the scope getting created on the first press with Batarang.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Edit:
I found some more information that might be helpful. The first time I click the link, the scope.closeFormModal gets called.

Comment: Ever got this working?  Same issue for me.  I trace it back to $modal.open().then code.  It has something to do with that promise being trigger on animation event.  I chalk it up as a bug and use angular strap instead.

Comment: Yeah, I did the same actually.

Comment: Angular-ui-bootstrap and bootstrap both try to catch a click, 1 catches the first click, lets through to the event but the next is also waiting for a click...

Answer (score 0):

Try add:

```
 scope.$watch(
    function () {
        return scope.formModal;
    },
    function (newData, oldData) {
        if (newData === oldData) {
            return;
        }
        if (newData) {
            $compile($element.contents())(scope);
        }
    });
```

to link function that was returned from $compile function.